# How to compare variables containing backslash-escaped commas in Selenium IDE?

Tags: web-applications, browser, selenium, automation, selenium-ide

I have a Selenium IDE script that reads a comma-separated list of values from an HTML file that I maintain, and stores this in a variable using storeSelectOptions. Then later, the script compares the contents of that variable with the options in a select element (droplist) on a page, using verifySelectOptions. The point of the script is to verify that the select element contains all the right values.

This works for all my droplists except one that contains a comma within one of the items. Since my variable contains a list of comma-separated items, this is a problem. When the variable is stored, it seems to escape the internal comma with a backslash, but then the verify operation fails because Selenium doesn't think that the two elements match. In other words, Selenium sees the droplist on the page as:

```
Red,
Green,
Blue, Dark
```

and it sees the variable as:

```
Red,
Green,
Blue\, Dark
```

Any thoughts as to how to fix this?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

For Comma separated values, You have to insert extra Backslash in value.
i.e. Use following value to Verify dropdown option value.

Blue\\\\\, Dark

Let me update, Is it working or not ?